# Is there a setting somewhere in MYDLL.dll to tell VS to include (the unreferenced) Bass.dll anytime MYDLL is added to another project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have written my own DLL.  Call it MYDLL.dll.

It uses Bass.Net.dll (for audio processing).   Bass.Net.dll itself requires Bass.dll an unmanged lib so I cannot add this to the References in my project.   So I have just added Bass.dll to my project files and set "COPY TO OUTPUT DIRECTORY" .  So everything is correctly placed in my bin folder when I build the project MYDLL.

Here is the problem - When I want to use MYDLL.DLL from another app.  I add a reference to MYDLL.DLL.  And VS 2010 is smart enough to also bring over Bass.Net.dll as well (since it was Referenced in the MYDLL project).  But it does not bring over the Bass.dll file.  I have to copy this manually.

Is there a setting somewhere in MYDLL.dll to tell VS to include (the unreferenced) Bass.dll anytime MYDLL is added to another project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the DLL in the referencing project as content, with Copy To Output = true.

Visual Studio doesn't recursively include the dependencies of dependencies which you reference. It is your responsibility to ensure that sub-dependencies are discoverable via normal Windows and .NET dependency resolution.

Comment: I wouldn't expcet VS to automatically handle sub-depencies like this.  I was hoping there was some sort of flag I could manually set on the 2nd dll in the original project.  Like "DISTRIBUTE THIS FILE WITH DLL" or some such thing.  But I am sensing that doesn't exist.   So I'll mark your response as the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: That's right, that mechanism doesn't exist as a relation between files, or as a project attribute in Visual Studio which would get it to do the copy for you. In general, control over deployment of dependencies is completely left to the developer.